# Missing content during browser resize despite % widths and heights

Tags: html, css, resize

I am currently facing an issue with browser resizing. When the page is at full size (i.e. the browser window is not being minimised), the page works well, yielding this:

[image]

However, when I minimise the window, making it smaller by compressing it vertically, this happens:

[image]

The content is cut off, and I cannot scroll to view the full content in the resized browser window.

I understand that this is a common issue. I have tried to resolve this by ensuring that:

- any widths are in terms of % (and indeed, everything scales well
  with respect to the width)
- heights are `auto` (so that they wrap the necessary content)

When that did not work out, I replaced the height values with % values instead of simply using `auto`, making sure that the total height values did not exceed 100%. Unfortunately, that did not work out either. Any idea why, and what I can do to make this work? Thanks in advance!

My HTML and CSS can be found here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yoBEWb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `height: 100vh;` with `min-height: 100vh;`

Comment: One single line, and you resolved 2 hours of debugging. Thanks! One last question: why is it that this particular page might require setting min-height to 100vh while other pages had no issues with just height: 100vh?

Comment: you're welcome, setting height to 100% will force the height to 100% of viewport no matter how much content so it will hide  the rest, while min-height it can be more than 100vh

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Media queries** to resize properly your screen and adapt your content. Basically a media query is something like a rule saying for example : if my screen height is less or equal to 480px then please reduce the font-size, place it below...More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned it in my question, but I have also heard about media queries before. The question that I am now interested in is why my current approach is not working, but thanks again for suggesting media queries